# Could not load local video using PrettyPhoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, prettyphoto

I am trying to load a video saved in videos folder in my project. In my `aspx` file, I wrote the following code:

```
<div class="boxcontainer">
    <span class="gallery">
        <a data-gal="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" href="videos/doc.mov"><img src="http://placehold.it/275x180"  alt=""></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

And the `javascript` part:

```
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<!-- CALL lightbox prettyphoto -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[data-gal^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({ social_tools: '', animation_speed: 'normal', theme: 'dark_rounded' });
    });
</script>
```

When I run the project, and click on the image, I am getting a blank window in firefox as shown in the below figure:

[image]

And in Chrome, I get the following:

[image]

What could be the issue that is preventing the video to be loaded?

Comment: quicktime is not supported. also please remove references to .net, it has nothing to do with that

Comment: so what could be the solution?

Comment: convert the video to a supported format or host it on youtube.

Comment: .mp4 is a common format.

Comment: I also tried to use mp4 but i got the following message: Image cannot be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and image exist

Comment: Did you got any solution for it?because i also suffering same problem